# My Anycubic i3 Mega S stops working

Tags: firmware, anycubic-i3-mega, repair

I have an Anycubic i3 Mega S and I'm using Ultimaker Cura. I'm using it for 1-2 years but 1-2 months ago this issue has started: The printer is starting to print then usually after 2-3 loops, it just stops working. I can't stop & pause the printing (it gives an error) and I have to turn off the printer.

I reinstalled the firmware multiple times with both Ultimaker and SuperSlicer but it is still happening. I have tried to use different slicer software, models (STL files), SD cards, and none of them worked.

Also recently I noticed something weird: this problem happens when the model is bigger than 5-8 cm. Like it happened when I tried to print a 10x10 cm model but I split the model into two parts and it worked fine. Also, it's about the area of the model's bottom. For example, if the model has a skirt bigger than 5-8 cm, it causes this issue but when I remove the skirt then it works fine.

BTW, I checked the G-code and didn't notice anything unusual and even with different slicer software, the exact spot where the printer stopped doesn't change.

I don't think the STL file is causing this because, for example, if I want to print a 5x8x3 cm model, I can't place it horizontally (5x8 area at the bottom) but I can place it vertically (5x3 area at the bottom) and it works fine.

Settings:

- Print speed: 50 mm/s
- Travel speed: 100 mm/s
- Nozzle temperature: 200 °C
- Bed temperature: 60 °C
- PLA filament
- Retraction distance: 6 mm
- Retraction Speed: 40 mm/s

I'm using a Volcano V6 hotend

I'm using stock 1.1.5 firmware:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/176Zdtz8-ZvCqL7MgupIVYgKVEnWnkPmW/view

Comment: Have you checked the bed dimensions in your slicer? The presets may have changed for some reason, which might be causing you issues.

Comment: Yeah I was using same settings I used before in Cura  and When I was testing in different slicers, I certainly know  it's the right dimensions I entered (210x210x250 mm)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues with the Mega S. After checking all the connections and switches, I saved all the files that were on the SD card to my laptop. I then performed a standard format (not a Quick format) on the SD card. After that was accomplished, I put the files back on; success, the printer works fine. Apparently the random writes on the SD card and not knowing where the G-code or STL was dropped can make the printer confused seeing a G-code file that has to be read continuously step by step.